# Celery hangs when publish a task with incorrect broker url

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, redis, celery

First of all, I would like to apologize for bad English.

I'm using celery with flask-restful. And when I trying publish celery task, the entire process hangs indefinitely. This occurs when I specify an incorrect value of broker url in celery config.

How I can fix this? How I can set timeout for task publishing and how I can set max retries to publish task?

I tried to use task_publish_retry directive set to False, but it's not work for me.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot provide a valid broker URL?

Comment: I want to handle this issue by myself. It's not just a matter of valid broker_url, I need to handle this if my broker is down.

Comment: @Vir I do have the same problem integrating Celery with Django. I've shut down my RabbitMQ instance to test how Celery behave when the broker does not respond and it is hanging forever. 
After digging into the code of Celery, it seems the connection timeout & max_retries are not passed when initializing the broker connection. Did you find any solutions meanwhile?

Comment: damn I just also bumped on this issue, trying to replicate a broken connection in a test!

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into the same issue and could not find a solution yet, but it seems like a bug to me so I've opened an issue on github: [Celery hangs indefinitely (instead of failing) if redis is not started #4556](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4556).

Comment: It's still an issue as of 4.3.